# How to bind Itemssource of combobox in xceed datagrid

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I am trying to add a combobox to a Xceed WPF datagrid but not able to bind Itemssource to the combo box. Here is the xaml for the datagrid.

```
<xwpf:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding SaleDetails}" AutoCreateColumns="False"  >
        <xwpf:DataGridControl.Columns>
            <xwpf:Column FieldName="Status" Title="Status" CellContentTemplate="{StaticResource colReinstatementType}" CellEditor="{StaticResource statusEditor}" />
        </xwpf:DataGridControl.Columns>
</xwpf:DataGridControl>
```

Resources

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="colReinstatementType">
            <ComboBox BorderThickness="0"
                      x:Name="cmbStatus1"
                      IsReadOnly="False"
                      IsEditable="True"
                      MinHeight="20"
                      DisplayMemberPath="part_no"
                      Text="{xwpf:CellEditorBinding NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"  
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding AvailablePartMaterial, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
        <xwpf:CellEditor x:Key="statusEditor">
            <xwpf:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox BorderThickness="0"
                              x:Name="cmbStatus"
                              IsReadOnly="False"
                              IsEditable="True"
                              MinHeight="20"
                              DisplayMemberPath="part_no"
                              Text="{xwpf:CellEditorBinding NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"  
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding AvailablePartMaterial, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xwpf:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
        </xwpf:CellEditor>            
     </UserControl.Resources>
```

`Item` and `AvailablePartMaterial` do exist in the `SaleSheet` type whose collection is bound to the datagrid. Even `Item` property does get fired which means Selected item of the combo box is getting binded. But no data is shown in the combo box.

Comment: Can you check the output window for binding failure logs?

Comment: thr is no binding failure in the output window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CellContentTemplate is meant for display purposes only. Usually it is used to display text using something like a TextBlock. In the cases where an editor type must be used (such as a CheckBox on a Boolean column), you will want to make it ReadOnly to avoid any unwanted issues.

In your case, you have a ComboBox with a CellEditorBinding as the CellContentTemplate. The CellEditorBinding only works in a CellEditor, so if the user is editing the row's value by using the CellContentTemplate's ComboBox, it will have no impact on the underlying value.

For your bindings, try something like this instead:

```
SelectedValuePath="part_no"   // name of column used to identify which record is selected
DisplayMemberPath="part_name" // name of column used to indicate the text/value to display
SelectedValue = {xwpf:CellEditorBinding} // SelectedItem or SelectedIndex can be used instead, depending on the situation/data
```

In regards to the ItemsSource, you cannot bind to it directly while you are inside a CellEditor's DataTemplate, you need to indicate where it is located. For example:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=MyData}">
```